# What are all the special naming conventions that Unity considers in the asset importer?

Tags: unity, asset-workflow, documentation

Scanning through some [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/importing-lod-meshes.html), it's apparent that the Unity Asset Importing workflow has some built-in special behaviors that are triggered by asset naming conventions.

For instance, with LODs, by following the naming convention of adding a `_LOD0`, `_LOD1`, `_LOD2` etc suffix to submeshes of an asset, Unity will automatically create a LOD Group component and set up the LOD levels.

[image: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/importing-lod-meshes.html]

I've scanned through the docs for other special naming conventions, but I haven't found anything else. Is there a comprehensive list of all naming conventions that the Unity Asset Importer considers on import, and what the importer does with those assets?

Comment: Be aware that there are also special folder names: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html

Comment: I am aware of those and thankfully they're well documented. I wish unity had a page like that for the asset importer.